# IE hides part of text input field on focus

Tags: internet-explorer, text, input, field, onfocus

The issue is that IE hides part of text input field on focus and even when not focused, one character is still hided. 
I tried `input[type="text"]::ms-clear {display:none;}` which helped to have less part to be hided but still one character is almost hided. below are the attached screenshots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVNXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is only to have `font: inherit;` and no need for ms-clear.

Thanks
Ramin